# Checking disk size of Bitmap before applying

Tags: android, android-bitmap

We're applying a full page bitmap and want to avoid memory errors.  What we're attempting to do is compare the bitmap file size to the available memory and either shrinking it down or simply applying it.

Questions:  Would this accomplish that?  Is there a better way?

Here's how we're doing it (we're semi-new to Kotlin as well so syntax suggestions are also appreciated) ->

```
private suspend fun getFullScreenBitmap(page: MyFullPage): Bitmap? = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var inputStream: FileInputStream? = null
        val cachedPageFile: File = getFileFromStorage(page)
        var pageImage: Bitmap?
        try {
            inputStream = FileInputStream(cachedPageFile)
            val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options)
            val originalWidth = options.outWidth
            val originalHeight = options.outHeight

            // We will calculate the highest res image
            val displayMetrics = getContext().resources.displayMetrics
            val reqWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels //imageView.getWidth();
            val reqHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels //imageView.getHeight();

            //get max heap available to app
            val activityManager = getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            val maxHeap: Int = activityManager.memoryClass //MB

            //get current heap used by app
            val runtime: Runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
            val usedHeap = ((runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / (1024.0f * 1024f)) //MB

            //get amount of free heap remaining for app
            val availableHeap = maxHeap - usedHeap
            val bitmapSize = originalWidth * originalHeight * 4f/1024f * 1024f //MB

            if (bitmapSize > availableHeap) {
                options.inSampleSize = getGoogleSuggestedInSampleSize()
            }
            inputStream.close()

            // Load in actual image
            inputStream = FileInputStream(cachedPageFile)
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565

            options.inMutable = (FeatureConstants.DEBUG_DOUBLE_TAPS_ENABLED || FeatureConstants.DEBUG_PANELS_ENABLED)

            pageImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options)

            return@withContext pageImage

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            GravLog.error(TAG, e.toString())
            NewRelic.recordHandledException(e)
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    GravLog.error(TAG, e.toString())
                    NewRelic.recordHandledException(e)
                }

            }
        }
        return@withContext null
    }
```

Comment: What do you consider a bitmaps file size? Mostly a bitmap does not exist on file but only in memory. On file there is jpg and png and so.

Comment: Looking for the size of the final rendered image.  We download the image from a server, save it to the device, then display it by pulling the saved file and converting it to a bitmap.

Comment: It is unclear what you consider to be the size of the final rendered image.